# Add Border to li element on Click

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want to add Left Border to li element and change its Background Color when I click on it.
The Background Color is change fine but the problem in the Left Border is not work.

HTML code:

```js
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {

        $('li').click(function () {

            $('li').addClass('active');
        });
    })
```

```css
    li {
        background-color: grey;
        border-left: 3px solid blue;
    }
    
    .active {
        background-color: blue;
        border-left: 4px solid red;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <ul>
        <li><span>Option 1</span></li>
        <li><span>Option 2</span></li>
        <li><span>Option 3</span></li>
        <li><span>Option 4</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It is working as expected. What are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: It not work on my case, not wok in my project, i do not know what is the problem

Comment: Do you mean that the border color is not getting changed in your project? Try running the code snippet in your question and the color is changing in here

Comment: @user8328264 Open F12 and look in console if you have any error + look in Element to see what happen to the style

Comment: I got it, just i needed to add ( !impotant ) in css code for border and it work fine, Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

use pseudo-classes. no need JS or jQuery. Like that

change this.

```
  .active {
    background-color: blue;
    border-left: 4px solid red;
}
```

to this.

```
li:active {
    background-color: blue;
    border-left: 4px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the active class to all list elements, that is why it is not behaving as required. Active class should only be added to the clicked list element.Your JS should be

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {

        $('li').click(function () {
              // remove the current active class from other element
              $('li').removeClass('active');

            //add the active class to the clicked element
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    })
```

UPDATED with Code Snippet

```js
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {

        $('li').click(function () {
              $('li').removeClass('active');

            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    })
```

```css
 li {
        background-color: grey;
        border-left: 3px solid blue;
    }
    
    .active {
        background-color: blue;
        border-left: 4px solid red;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <ul>
        <li><span>Option 1</span></li>
        <li><span>Option 2</span></li>
        <li><span>Option 3</span></li>
        <li><span>Option 4</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That is not the problem, even Active class added to the clicked element the border not work with me

Comment: @user8328264 I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jkzrfpbh/1/) for this. Hope it helps

Comment: @ajayramgarhia You can add the fiddle as a [code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269753/13833218) on your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  $('li').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Is just need to add !important to css code:

```
.active {
    background-color: blue;
    border-left: 4px solid red !important;
}
```